# Prove that $L$, $M$, and $N$ are collinear.

Tags: geometry, contest-math

> Let $G$ denote the centroid of $\triangle ABC$;  $AG$ is produced to $X$ such that $GX = AG$. If we draw parallels through $X$ to $CA$, $AB$, and $BC$ meeting $BC$, $CA$, and $AB$ at $L$, $M$, and $N$ respectively, prove that $L$, $M$, and $N$ are collinear.

This question is from an ebook (source: CTPCM).

I am unable to proceed in the question. I applied Ceva's Theorem and proportionality theorem, but I get stuck leading nowhere.

Comment: it would be good, if down post is added with a comment.

Comment: Probably because you didn't really explain what your effort towards the problem

Comment: @QuangHoang : Kindly Help!!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[image]
Let $D$ be the intersection of line $XL$ with $AB$, $F$ the intersection of $XM$ and $BC$, and $E$ the midpoint of $BC$ (so $A$, $G$, and $E$ are colinear).

Since $XL\parallel AC$, $\triangle XLE$ is similar to $\triangle ACE$, and we have
$$AE:EX=EC:EL=AC:XL=3:1.\tag{1}$$
Similarly, $\triangle XEF$ is similar to $\triangle ABE$ and
$$AE:EX=BE:EF=AB:FX=3:1.\tag{2}$$
From $EC:EL=BE:EF=3:1$ and $BE=EC$, we see that $BL=LF=FC=BC/3$.

Since $DL\parallel AC$, we have
$$AC:DL=BC:BL=3:1.$$
This and (2) imply that $DL=XL$. So $L$ is the midpoint of $XD$. Similarly, $F$ is the midpoint of $XM$. So $DM\parallel LF$ and both of them are parallel to $XN$.

It follows that $DMXN$ is a parallelogram (having parallel opposite edges). That means $MN$ contains the midpoint of $DX$, which is $L$.

Comment: I think your answer is wrong ..... how AE/EX=3/1 this means yu are saying that E is midpoint of GX which is not given ...

Comment: Not given but deduced from the proof. Also, the fact that $E$ is the midpoint of $GX$ is not used in this proof.

Comment: Thanks for replying.....can yu pls tell how you written AE/EX = OTHER RATIOS = 3/1  in the starting  .....I know centroid property but I couldn't deduce this....

Comment: Ha, now that you say it. Yes, I implicitly did use the fact that $E$ is the midpoint of $GX$ for that purpose. But it comes straight from the fact that $G$ is the centroid and also midpoint of $AX$, plus $E$ is the midpoint of $BC$. Thanks for your comment.

Comment: Sorry, but can you pls elaborate why E is mid point of GX using what yu claim...

Comment: since $G$ is the centroid, $AG:GE = 2:1$. That means $XG:GE=2:1$ because $AG=GX$ as given.

Comment: Ahh...silly me  thanks